# Autodetect classes in Hibernate from jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a JavaEE project with several entities with the following `persistence.xml` file:

```
...
<properties>
    <!-- Scan for annotated classes -->
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
...
```

And it seems to work. The project is then deployed as a JAR to two different projects. In one them, the `persistence.xml` file is basically the same as the one above, i.e. uses the `autodetection` feature of Hibernate. However, it does not seem to work (because I think it needs to load search for the entities in a jar). When I tried manually listing all the entities in both xml files, everything works correctly.

**Edit:** It works with **jar-file** but only with the absolute path to the jar. Pretty useless for a team project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read you correctly, in the case where it does not work, the entities are in a *different* JAR than the persistence.xml that's used, right?

I think you're correct that's the problem. You need to tell Hibernate which JAR(s) to scan using the **jar-file** element. 
See the explanation and examples in the Hibernate docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging)

Comment: But what is the correct path for the jar file? Everything I try leads to a `The system cannot find the path specified`?

Comment: This stackoverflow question might help: [what is the right path to refer a jar file in jpa persistence.xml in a web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433341/what-is-the-right-path-to-refer-a-jar-file-in-jpa-persistence-xml-in-a-web-app). 
**Edit** Oops, I just saw your edit - guess you figured it out already. Sorry, and yeah, I thought the same thing reading about the absolute path requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I think Hibernate only scans for JPA Entities inside jar files, and not in classes/ folders for example, or it only scans in the jar with the persistence.xml, or something like that. Instead of trying to bend the Hibernate scanner, I felt it would be easier to scan for entities myself. It is a lot easier than I anticipated.

```
 val entities = mutableListOf<Class<*>>()
AnnotationDetector(object : AnnotationDetector.TypeReporter {
    override fun reportTypeAnnotation(annotation: Class<out Annotation>?, className: String?) {
        entities.add(Class.forName(className))
    }

    override fun annotations(): Array<out Class<out Annotation>> = arrayOf(Entity::class.java)
}).detect("com.github")

VaadinOnKotlin.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sample", mapOf(AvailableSettings.LOADED_CLASSES to entities))
```

I have used the detector which is built-in in the atmosphere jar file; but you can use perhaps https://github.com/rmuller/infomas-asl or others as stated here: [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)
The full code example is located here: https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin-on-kotlin/blob/master/vok-example-crud/src/test/java/com/github/vok/example/crud/Server.kt

None of the following helped: adding

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

to the `persistence.xml` file did nothing (according to doc it is ignored in JavaSE anyway); adding

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
```

to the `persistence.xml` file did nothing (I'm not using hbm anyways). Don't waste your time trying to add those, they won't enable proper auto-scan.

Answer (score 0):

Using the empty element `<jar-file></jar-file>` works e.g. with WildFly 8.2.1.Final (Hibernate 4.3.7.Final) :) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908447/1915920).
(`<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />` did not work)

(but it did not work outside of WildFly for Eclipse-run JUnit tests where we had to remove it. Which is not a problem since the libraries are already in the classpath. The error was something like: `java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 5: file:> => <java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to visit JAR file:. Cause: Expected scheme-specific part at index 5: file:> => <javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory`)