# Hibernate - scan entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm entry level Java developer and I have project with Hibernate and property file `hibernate.cfg.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC                            
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Group"></mapping>
        <mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Movement"></mapping>
        <mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Product"></mapping>
        <mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Description"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

How I can set auto scanning of entity classes and delete this rows?

```
<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Group"></mapping>
<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Movement"></mapping>
<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Product"></mapping>
<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Description"></mapping>
```

Comment: From the DTD: `<!ATTLIST mapping package CDATA #IMPLIED>` so `<mapping package="..."/>`

Comment: I replace snippet of code :

`<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Group"></mapping>
<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Movement"></mapping>
<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Product"></mapping>
<mapping class="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Description"></mapping>`

by

`<mapping package="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity"/>` but it still don't work. @RC

Answer (score 0):

When you define `sessionfactory` bean in spring context file, you can use `packagesToScan` property and `@Entity` annotation to achieve this.

Code snippet:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  ... //other properties
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="ua.com.vtkachenko.entity">
  ../other properties
</bean>
```

Now write `@Entity` annotation above entity classes. Also your entity class should have `@Column` annotation to get mapped with table columns.

Hope it helps. If you any issue, please let me know.

Comment: I insert this into my app-context.xml and get error

_Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ua.com.vtkachenko.entity.Group
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:548)..............._

Comment: I think that it is correct way to solve it when you use Spring with Hibernate.
In my example I have such project structure
![Screenshot](https://s18.postimg.org/w29vccrih/Screenshot_from_2016_12_05_16_16_19.png).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to learn instead of this: Spring boot and JPA.

It would save you many headaches if your aim is just learning, imho.

Regards

Comment: Spring Boot and JPA indeed provides a really neat quickstart, but then I got severe headaches while fighting with injections and debugging Spring (Spring is HUGE and overwhelming). I eventually gave up and stopped using Spring and JavaEE altogether, and moved to this: https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin-on-kotlin (disclaimer - I'm the author)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want to use Spring, here's a solution with pure Hibernate on JavaSE - this will scan your entire classpath for JPA entities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845759/377320